# How to move scrollbar to the left in gnome terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome

I'm using gnome shell 3.22.3 with the classic theme on RHEL 7.4 beta and I want to move the scrollbar of the gnome-terminal to the left side of the window.

I tried adding

```
gtk-scrolled-window-placement = top-right
```

to .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini as suggested in bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157025. [But this setting is apparently ignored since version 3.10 of GTK.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-scrolled-window-placement)

Then I tried adding

```
TerminalScreenContainer {
 -TerminalScreenContainer-window-placement: bottom-right;
 -TerminalScreenContainer-window-placement-set: true;
}
```

to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css as mentioned [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#How_can_I_move_the_scroll_bar_to_the_left_side_of_the_window_.28like_in_xterm.29.3F). But that's not working either.

EDIT:

```
* {
 -TerminalScreenContainer-window-placement: bottom-right;
 -TerminalScreenContainer-window-placement-set: true;
}
```

is working, so now I only have to find out which class is correct.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=772134.

Answer (score 0):

In the gtk.css file, the class to use is:

```
terminal-screen-container {
```

(with hyphens) instead of `TerminalScreenContainer`.